# How do I handle errors when using api_auth gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest-client, api-auth

Currently for a project I am using `api_auth` gem. I am hitting on an external api in a function by making a signed request. Currently my code looks like this.

```
access_id = "someKey"
secret_key = "someRandomGeneratedKey"
request = RestClient::Request.new(url: 'serverUrl', method: get, headers:'headers')

@signed_request = ApiAuth.sign!(access_id, secret_key, request)
@signed_request.execute
```

I am unable to apply any error handling code to that last statement where I execute the request. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use begin rescue block to exception handling.

```
begin
    #TODO Exception occurring statement
rescue 
    #Exception handling code
end
```

As you should only rescue specific exception, rather than all.
So as your code suggest that you are using `rest_client` & `api-auth` gem so from documentation you can get list of exception that this gem raise.

Example - For `rest_client` below exceptions need to be handled. (probably this is the solution of your problem, just replace last line as given below)

```
begin 
    @signed_request.execute
rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse, URI::InvalidURIError, RestClient::InternalServerError => err
    p err
end
```

There are few Exceptions also generated by `api-auth` gem also like 
`ApiAuth::ApiAuthError`, `ApiAuth::UnknownHTTPRequest` so you need to rescue all this exceptions.

Reference link -

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/api-auth/1.4.0/

Thanks!

Comment: @wallydrag - is this answer helps?